# QGIS WKT export not importing as closed polygon to Google MyMaps correctly

Tags: qgis, well-known-text, google-mymaps

I am attempting to export a small area geography file from QGIS into Google MyMaps in a CSV WKT format. Whilst it displays absolutely fine if exported as .kml, when I import it as the WKT, a few shapes are incomplete and therefore don't shade correctly.

Image below shows an example - three shapes displaying fine as KML, but the middle one is incomplete when exported as WKT. Link to the map is:  [Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/edit?mid=11CXMdUE14t-uLuFD6O2X8jp-zuJedCk&usp=sharing)

[image]

I've experimented with deleting vertices down the river section, and at some point, it starts importing as a filled shape. I thought this meant it was a dodgy vertex, but in attempting to isolate the section, I found that deleting different sets of vertices elsewhere similarly made it complete the shape.

It has more vertices than most shapes in the file, but there are others with more that draw correctly. Is there a field character limit to WKT imports in mymaps, and if not, what other geometry errors should I be checking?

Files are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ylhJfsLuTR26LdmIlWoeIs1l-X-AzjgJ?usp=sharing).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the polygon valid?

Comment: quickly ran through your file with exporting via KML Tools in QGIS 3.2.0 Lima https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/kmltools/ and have no issues viewing all polygons in Google Earth.

Comment: Polygons should be. They pass the geometry checker and are extracted from an official national dataset, so well validated. KML works absolutely fine, as per the map - it's just the WKT that seems to not close the circle.